# Installing el-get for managing packages in Emacs 24.3

Tags: emacs

The instructions for installing [`el-get`](https://github.com/dimitri/el-get) say the following:

```
;; Copy/paste this code into your *scratch* buffer,
;; hit C-j, and you have a working el-get.
(url-retrieve
 "https://raw.github.com/dimitri/el-get/master/el-get-install.el"
 (lambda (s)
   (goto-char (point-max))
   (eval-print-last-sexp)))
```

When I do so, a buffer called `*Backtrace*` opens up in `debugger-mode` with the following contents:

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (void-variable closed)
  eval(closed nil)
  eval-last-sexp-1(t)
  eval-last-sexp(t)
  eval-print-last-sexp()
  (lambda (s) (goto-char (point-max)) (eval-print-last-sexp))(nil)
  apply((lambda (s) (goto-char (point-max)) (eval-print-last-sexp)) nil)
  url-http-activate-callback()
  url-http-content-length-after-change-function(589 3952 3363)
  url-http-generic-filter(#<process raw.github.com> ";;; el-get-install.el --- installer for the lazy
;;
;; Copyright (C) 2010 Dimitri Fontaine
;;
;; Author: Dimitri Fontaine <dim@tapoueh.org>
;; URL: http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/el-get.el
;; Created: 2010-06-17
;; Keywords: emacs package elisp install elpa git git-svn bzr cvs apt-get fink http http-tar
;; Licence: WTFPL, grab your copy here: http://sam.zoy.org/wtfpl/
;;
;; This file is NOT part of GNU Emacs.
;;
;; bootstrap your el-get installation, the goal is then to use el-get to
;; update el-get.
;;
;; So the idea is that you copy/paste this code into your *scratch* buffer,
;; hit C-j, and you have a working el-get.

(let ((el-get-root
       (file-name-as-directory
    (or (bound-and-true-p el-get-dir)
        (concat (file-name-as-directory user-emacs-directory) \"el-get\")))))

  (when (file-directory-p el-get-root)
    (add-to-list 'load-path el-get-root))

  ;; try to require el-get, failure means we have to install it
  (unless (require 'el-get nil t)
    (unless (file-directory-p el-get-root)
      (make-directory el-get-root t))

    (let* ((package   \"el-get\")
       (buf       (switch-to-buffer \"*el-get bootstrap*\"))
       (pdir      (file-name-as-directory (concat el-get-root package)))
       (git       (or (executable-find \"git\")
              (error \"Unable to find `git'\")))
       (url       (or (bound-and-true-p el-get-git-install-url)
              \"http://github.com/dimitri/el-get.git\"))
       (default-directory el-get-root)
       (process-connection-type nil)   ; pipe, no pty (--no-progress)

       ;; First clone el-get
       (status
        (call-process
         git nil `(,buf t) t \"--no-pager\" \"clone\" \"-v\" url package)))

      (unless (zerop status)
    (error \"Couldn't clone el-get from the Git repository: %s\" url))

      ;; switch branch if we have to
      (let* ((branch (cond
                      ;; Check if a specific branch is requested
                      ((bound-and-true-p el-get-install-branch))
                      ;; Check if master branch is requested
                      ((boundp 'el-get-master-branch) \"master\")
                      ;; Read the default branch from the el-get recipe
                      ((plist-get (with-temp-buffer
                                    (insert-file-contents-literally
                                     (expand-file-name \"recipes/el-get.rcp\" pdir))
                                    (read (current-buffer)))
                                  :branch))
                      ;; As a last resort, use the master branch
                      (\"master\")))
             (remote-branch (format \"origin/%s\" branch))
             (default-directory pdir)
             (bstatus
               (if (string-equal branch \"master\")
                 0
                 (call-process git nil (list buf t) t \"checkout\" \"-t\" remote-branch))))
        (unless (zerop bstatus)
          (error \"Couldn't `git checkout -t %s`\" branch)))

      (add-to-list 'load-path pdir)
      (load package)
      (let ((el-get-default-process-sync t) ; force sync operations for installer
            (el-get-verbose t))         ; let's see it all
        (el-get-post-install \"el-get\"))
      (unless (boundp 'el-get-install-skip-emacswiki-recipes)
        (el-get-emacswiki-build-local-recipes))
      (with-current-buffer buf
    (goto-char (point-max))
    (insert \"\
Congrats, el-get is installed and ready to serve!\")))))
closed
")
```

Do I take that there is an error in the file `https://raw.github.com/dimitri/el-get/master/el-get-install.el` ? Or is there anything else that I have to setup to get such a script working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Somehow the downloaded file gets a `closed` line appended, which isn't present in the original file - not sure why, it doesn't happen for me.  It's visible at the very end of the backtrace.

You could copy the entire `el-get-install.el` file, paste into `*scratch*` and eval that with `C-j` instead.